# How to get HTTP protocol version from a given NSHTTPURLResponse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, nshttpurlresponse

From `NSHTTPURLResponse` documentation, I did not find a way to get the `HTTP` version `(i.e. "HTTP/1.1" or "HTTP/1.0")`.

`HTTP` header fields are available through all Header Fields property, however the `HTTP` protocol version is not given inside the header fields as it is not an `HTTP` header.

**Note:** init, `NSHTTPURLResponse` initializer 
`(initWithURL:statusCode:HTTPVersion:headerFields:)` does require the `HTTPVersion` as an input, so theoretically it may have been saved there.

However, I couldn't find a property or method to get the `HTTPVersion` from a given response, for example a response returned from an NSURLSessionDataTask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no public way to access the http version of an `NSHTTPURLResponse` instance, and the version of response is depended on the request version.

You can use `CFNetworking` if you really want to access the http version.

```
CFN_EXPORT CFHTTPMessageRef 
CFHTTPMessageCreateResponse(
  CFAllocatorRef  __nullable alloc,
  CFIndex         statusCode,
  CFStringRef     __nullable statusDescription,
  CFStringRef     httpVersion)              CF_AVAILABLE(10_1, 2_0);
```

And the `CFHTTPMessageCopyVersion()` returns the HTTP version.

Actually the `-[NSHTTPURLResponse initWithURL:(NSURL *)URL statusCode:(NSInteger)statusCode HTTPVersion:(NSString *)version headerFields:(NSDictionary *)fields]` uses `CFHTTPMessageCreateResponse` to create a HTTP response. see [NSURLResponse.m](https://github.com/apportable/Foundation/blob/f7fe19a8d9f98978b9dd72ae75c153943f958d5e/System/Foundation/src/NSURLResponse.m)

The `NSURLResponse` is backed upon the `_CFURLResponse` struct.

```
typedef struct _CFURLResponse {
    CFRuntimeBase _base;
    CFAbsoluteTime creationTime;
    CFURLRef url;
    CFStringRef mimeType;
    int64_t expectedLength;
    CFStringRef textEncoding;
    CFIndex statusCode;
    CFStringRef httpVersion;
    CFDictionaryRef headerFields;
    Boolean isHTTPResponse;

    OSSpinLock parsedHeadersLock;
    ParsedHeaders* parsedHeaders;
} _CFURLResponse;

typedef const struct _CFURLResponse* CFURLResponseRef;
```

You can get this struct using `_CFURLResponse` getter method on a `NSURLResponse` instance:

```
CFTypeRef test = CFBridgingRetain([response performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"_CFURLResponse")]);
CFShow(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don’t use `_CFURLResponse` private API, as CFNetwork doesn’t provide any guarantee of the format of its return value.

The recommended way to query HTTP version is to implement `URLSession:task:didFinishCollectingMetrics:` delegate method

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiontasktransactionmetrics/1643141-networkprotocolname?language=objc